# TableView header and footer with round corners using UIBezierPath

Tags: swift, uitableview, uibezierpath

I want to add round corners to top left and top right corner of a tableview header and to the two bottom corners of a tableview footer. I found UIBezierPath as solution, but my problem is that only one corner is round and the other one is not. Here is my code:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    let  headerCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("headerCell") as! myCustomHeaderCell


    let layer = CAShapeLayer()
    let corners = UIRectCorner.TopLeft.union(UIRectCorner.TopRight)
    layer.path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: headerCell.frame.width, height: headerCell.frame.height), byRoundingCorners: corners, cornerRadii:CGSizeMake(20.0, 20.0)).CGPath
    headerCell.layer.mask = layer
    return headerCell
}
```

Where is the mistake? What do I need to change to make it work?

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: this works for me as should be, so I can't reproduce your error, maybe your problem is with constraints instead

Answer (score 0):

I also found this issue when set bezier path along with constraints, but you can set headerCell.layer.cornerRadius = 20 replaced bezier, and then create a new view, set its backgroundColor as same as your headerCell's backgroundColor(in InterfaceBuilder or programming) set it above your headerCell to mask the headerCell bottomLeft and bottomRight round corner.

Comment: I second this approach!